# Docker - Windows 10 - An unexpected error was encountered while executing a WSL command

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I'm getting the below error after installing a new version of Docker Desktop:

> An unexpected error was encountered while executing a WSL command.
> Common causes include access rights issues, which occur after waking
> the computer or not being connected to your domain/active directory.
> Please try shutting WSL down (wsl --shutdown) and/or rebooting your
> computer. If not sufficient, WSL may need to be reinstalled fully. As
> a last resort, try to uninstall/reinstall Docker Desktop. If the issue
> persists please collect diagnostics and submit an issue
> (https://docs.docker.com/desktop/troubleshoot/overview/#diagnose-from-the-terminal).

Thanks in advance.
I am installing Docker Desktop in Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

That was the case I handled.
You need to install Ubuntu Distribution and set it as default Distribution of Windows Subsystem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Enable Virtualization by going into BIOS mode and find enable virtualization under CPU/Security or Intel CPU setting depending on machine brand

PS. Had the same issue on Lenovo ThinkCentre MiniPC